# Why is my voice changing?

Tags: vegetarianism

I'm vegan is about 1 year, and as time.
I felt my voice became deeper and more resonant.
I watched some of the monks has such voice
Why is my voice changing?

Comment: You are probably reaching puberty. :) Anyways, veganism is a dietary habit and has nothing to do with Buddhism. This question is better suited for http://health.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I agree. I don't think this is really a question about Buddhism so doesn't belong on the site in my opinion. Sorry

Comment: I guess that the pitch (whether it's "deeper") is related to how tight your [vocal cords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_folds) are; and how "resonant" it is may depend on details of your breathing (including your [diaphragm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoracic_diaphragm)) but see also [Vocal resonation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_resonation).

Comment: I don't mind this question; it would have been nice if it included "from a Buddhist perspective", but I think we can assume it is implied. Even if the answer is simply "Buddhism says nothing about this", it still seems valuable to have it on our site.

Comment: I don't know whether [lion's roar](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/wheel390.html) is meant to imply anything about the tone of voice (except confidence); "voice deep and resonant" is one of the [Physical characteristics of the Buddha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_characteristics_of_the_Buddha).

Comment: If the implication is that veganism changes one's voice, then I'd want to say that this doesn't belong on the site, except that I think some schools of Buddhism do advocate something like vegetarianism, and thus may have something to say about the benefits.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably to do with the absence of tension. When you're relaxed, your voice tends to be lower. If you meditate or do yoga the voice naturaly goes in that direction. It's possible something similar happens when you eat very healthy and remove other kinds of tensions.

Comment: I agree. This happens to monks too, I think; tension can make one high-pitched.

Comment: Yes, Bhante. And everyone can remember some ocasion in their life when a big problem was just solved and they sigh with relief and peaceful relaxation. Right after this, the voice is lower. This is what happens in the long run with the problem of suffering itself.

Answer (score 1):

The voice is a "wind-instrument" and it relies on resonance. We have different cavities in the body, e.g. the nasal cavity and the chest cavity. These cavities are where the sound vibrations resonate and thereby gain frequency, e.g. low or high frequency.

When there is tension in the body, i.e. in muscles and ligaments there is restriction and contraction creating less space for the sound vibrations to resonate in. Sound vibrations love more space and tension kills them. Relaxation is important in order to create rich sound vibrations. A lowering of the voice can take place if there is a "bigger" cavity to resonate in, due to less tension in the body, thereby giving the vibrations a larger range of frequency to resonate in.

Its difficult to answer whether or not vegetarianism plays a role in your voice changing. There are many factors involved. You could try asking the question on the other SE's, e.g. *"Health and Biology"* to gain more answers or ask your doctor for a strictly medical answer if thats what your looking for. I would say get a lot of different opinions on it instead of limiting yourself to one perspective. Then you can evaluate the different answers you got and find out which one fits the best.

---

From a **buddhist perspective** an answer will be that your voice changes because it belongs to the 5 aggregates, i.e. the 1st aggregate of form. These aggregates are subject to the 3 signs of existence and therefore they are unstable, in a constant flux and ever-changing.

Comment: I think we should just assume an implied "from a Buddhist perspective" with such questions... I don't think we need close this one, since we can answer either a) Buddhism doesn't have anything to say about that, or b) Buddhism says x about that.

Comment: @Bhante. I see your point and i have retracted my close-vote.